# Print second page on the second column in Access Report

Tags: ms-access, report

Good day guys,

I work for a retail company and I was tasked to design a pricing list book. I have two columns, but it still just prints as one page. How do I force column two to display as page two?

I am using Access 2013.

Here is the image of what I have and what I want to achieve:

[image]

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Access can't do this automatically, you have to do it manually.

In the page header:

- duplicate the "Price List" header above the area where the 2nd column will be (use print preview to fine-tune)
- also duplicate the `Page` textbox:

In the left column, use `="Page " & [Page]*2-1`
In the right column, use `="Page " & [Page]*2`

So the first physical page will contain "logical pages" 1 & 2, the 2nd page will have 3 & 4 etc.